# asp.net MVC memory stream DICOM image to session variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, session-variables, dicom

I am generating images on fly from DICOM files using:

```
   public ActionResult Generatemage()
        {
            FileContentResult data;
.....
    objImage = im.Bitmap(outputSize, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, m);

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
    }
      return data;
        }
```

Can I store the image as a session variable so I can modify it using Point3D? 
I tried to use:

```
 Bitmap data = (Bitmap)Session["newimage"];
```

Got these two errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult' and 
A local variable named 'data' is already defined in this scope
```

I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I store the image as a session variable so I can modify it using
>   Point3D?

I suggest to not do that. If you have not [read Nathanael's post on image resizing pitfalls](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls) then I suggest you do so now. It may be talking about resizing but it also give hints on working with images **in general**. On point #3 it says:

> Serving a file from disk by loading it into memory. Think about how
>   much RAM your server has, how large a single image is, how long it has
>   to stay in memory before users fi downloading it, and how many
>   users you have requesting images.

In your particular case you can replace *"before users finish downloading it"* with *"before Point3D finish processing the image"*. So, what I suggest is that you get a handle to that file, say maybe there's an `Id` that uniquely identifies a file per user, use that `Id` to retrieve the file when it's time to process it with Point3D, load it into a `MemoryStream` (assuming Point3D can work with mem. stream), process it, then dispose of it. In that manner you are only holding on to the image for the duration of "Point3D processing".

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult' and  A local variable named 'data'
>   is already defined in this scope

That is most probably because you have defined `data` as such:

```
FileContentResult data;
```

and then you are doing a:

```
Bitmap data = (Bitmap)Session["newimage"];
```

same variable of two different types within the same scope.

Comment: Thank you Von, I have to figure out how to do it, but it is the right way to have a unique id to each file.